# Converter horário para quantidade segundos sem parte decimal

Tags: python

Estou tendo problemas em apresentar o resultado da transformação de um horário específico, na forma `HH:MM:SS`, todo em segundos. O resultado sai correto, porém com um `.0` no final, o que torna minha resposta inválida num site.

Meu código:

```
horario = input()
hora = float(horario[0:2])* int(3600)
minuto = float(horario[3:5])* int(60)
segundo = float(horario[6:8])
C = float(hora + minuto + segundo)
print(int(C))

# Saída: 18711.0
```

Comment: Não tem como a saída sair com o `.0` no final se está utilizando o `int`. Tem certeza que é este o código que você executou? Se sim, elabore um [mcve] no https://repl.it/languages/python3 demonstrando o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Lendo seu código e testando ele, a resposta é um valor inteiro mesmo, até porque não tem como sair float se você está convertendo no fim, em todo caso montei um exemplo só para comparar, utilizei o split só para ficar em um vetorzinho cada hora/min/seg para não precisar fazer os cortes de string, ele separa em toda ocorrência do caracter ':'

```
hora = input()
vetor = hora.split(":")
soma = 0
soma += int(vetor[0])*3600
soma += int(vetor[1])*60
soma += int(vetor[2])
print(soma)
```